# Does there exist a conservative algorithm to determine if a certain property is satisfied at a certain part of a program?

Tags: computability, correctness-proof, software-verification

```
...

x = a / b;
```

For the above code, for example, is there a way to determine whether `b` could be zero at the time of division, even if the answer isn't 100% decisive? Can this algorithm generalize to check any property at a point of a program?

Comment: You should define what exactly do you expect your algorithm to do. What exactly "even if the answer isn't 100% decisive" means? Do you want an algorithm that outputs the correct answer with some constant $>\frac{1}{2}$ probability? What kind of properties would you like to check, and for what types of programs? For almost any non trivial property, e.g. the one in your example, the task would be impossible for general problems.

Comment: This is just the halting problem in disguise.